# Firebase rules with user role

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

Observations :

```
+ observations
   + -KZHnCcoMXk9FyAfzdvB
     + animal: "Red fox"
     + location: "Berlin"
     + gps: null
     + note: null
     + creator
         + uid: "gyOhyfjj77VmF4JXeKSXKJlA3Yr2"
```

Users :

```
+ users
   + KzsNlmHLIGqf6Xfdcsw
      + id: "gyOhyfjj77VmF4JXeKSXKJlA3Yr2"
      + mail: "luke@gmail.com"
      + name: "Luke"
      + role: "admin"
```

Only admin can add new user, so I have to check if he's logged AND if he's admin (also if the data doesn't exist):

```
{
  "rules": {
      "users": {
        ".write": "auth != null && !data.exists() || !newData.exists() && ...
      }
   }
}
```

I do not know whether the user with "auth.uid" is the administrator or not. Maybe I should design the database in a different way.

Comment: Something to be aware of:  If you have a app with an admin user that can create other users you'll bump into a Firebase 'issue' whereas when a user is created in code, it logs out the current user (admin) and logs in the created user. There are some workarounds.

Comment: `root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('role').val() === 'admin'`